# WPF changing views in a window and executing different commands for each view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I want to build a window called NomenclaturesWindow.

[image]

The basic thing about this window is that it has all the buttons in the header and a list of items on the left as well as its own ViewModel(NomenclaturesViewModel). The items in the list can be of different types. Depending on the type of the item the view on the right is also different(the one in the picture is just one of the views). Each of the different views on the right has a ViewModel as well. And each of those ViewModels has its own logic for the New, Save, Delete, Undo buttons. I want to be able to control all of this from NomenclaturesViewModel. So for example, if the items in the list on the left are of type(Shifts) and I press New, NomenclaturesViewModel will go to ShiftsViewModel and execute the NewCommand. How can I achieve this? Plus I am using Catel.

Comment: The `DataContext` of the current view is the current view's view model. Each view is displayed by a common control. This hosting control must also expose the current view's view model or data context, but only the contract part. This means each view model must implement a common interface e.g. `IView` which declares the required command properties. Then simply bind your navigation bar to the data context (of type `IView`) of the host control.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am also using Catel and thus I think your suggestion will not work